# How can I propose a new Stack Exchange community?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I have just searched for a Business Analysts community in the Stack Exchange network but I could not find anything suitable.

What is the procedure for submitting a request for new community on the network?

Comment: Go to Area 51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Area51 says "unable to login" & "No user found", but no login window/page displayed. So how do I login?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you go to [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) to submit new community requests, but be sure to search the site for existing proposals before submitting a new request.

This seems like it might fit your request:

### [Business Intelligence](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence)

> Proposed Q&A site for collaborative Business Intelligence community (noob or pro) who nurture/discuss ideas/methodologies, value transactional data, create solutions, tools/softwares to address needs of BI, performance management and Business Analytics initiatives.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_analytics / http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_analyst - very different things

Comment: @Mat I'm not an expert in that area, it was just a suggestion that might fit the bill.

Comment: Not the same but thank you for the answer, there is one already created that matches more with BA topic