# How to start a new community?

Tags: support, meta

The community I want does not exist. How do I help start a new community?

I have searched the meta questions for answers as well as the stack overflow help. But I cannot find the answer.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: A StackExchange site? Go to http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on meta.stackexchange.com (where it's probably a duplicate).

Comment: It's easy to get confused between meta.stackechange.com and stack overflow meta. I see the difference now.

Comment: @S.L.Barth please see [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them).  Questions are not off topic "because they belong on MSE"

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks, I've read it now. I felt the close reason that the Close Votes queue gave was inappropriate, as the question _is_ about the software that powers the SE network. But there was no migration path to MSE - I understand why now.

Comment: I believe that this may be the proper MSO duplicate: [How can I propose a new Stack Exchange community?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294172/how-can-i-propose-a-new-stack-exchange-community)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by new community you mean a new Stack Exchange site then try [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/).