# Can we make Stack Overflow Student a success?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, quality-improvement, se-quality-project, area-51

Stack Overflow is [not for beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it.

This can create difficulties on the site when users are expected to have a minimal understanding of the problem. For example:

"What is a parameter?"

[image]

It is easy to post a link in the comments and tell the user to go  and this usually does not make the user feel welcomed. Why not have a site where the user can ask these types of questions?

A new site proposal in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

> Proposed Q&A site for students and novices in programming. Modelled on
>   the Stack Overflow site, but for beginner programmers. With the apt
>   acronym SOS.

This might be a way to assist in defining content on the Stack Overflow site itself, by shifting programming novices to a separate site.

The scope of the new site would need to be hashed out, which is why I'm bringing it here.

What can we do to make this site successful, both as a stand alone site and for Stack Overflow?

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Stack Overflow Student]

*The other considered name was Stack Overflow for Beginners which would become SOB.*

Comment: Beginner questions are not off-topic _here_, and you will start off with a distinct lack of experienced people answering questions _there_ (especially in niche topics), so I don't see how anyone would benefit with this proposal.

Comment: Here's the core question you have to answer: What, exactly, is pushing beginners away from SO that would be solved by this new site? If you can answer that convincingly, and in a way that wouldn't lead to a train wreck of a site, you've got a chance with this.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Needs to be more specific. What about beginners will be tolerated on this new site that isn't tolerated here?

Comment: The problem with questions from beginners and students _is not_ that the questions are beginner level or student level questions. The problem (with affected questions) is that they have a tendency to not follow the guidelines presented to them. This is a problem with users who are _new to asking questions_, not necessarily users who are new to a given concept, language, framework, what have you. You're not going to get around that on another site.

Comment: How will it be more tolerated? Here, you'll be pointed to [the first search result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)) for "what is a parameter in programming" and probably closed as a duplicate of something. You'll still have to close things as duplicates on SOS, and you'll still have occasional jerks to deal with.

Comment: @Yvette I don't know about your *parameters* but I'm not yet convinced by your *arguments* :p

Comment: @YvetteColomb Do you have an actual example of a question that is off-topic for Stack Overflow but would be on-topic for SOS? As far as I can tell "what is a parameter?" is an on-topic question. It has probably been asked and answered in some form already so it would probably be closed as a duplicate, but it isn't off-topic.

Comment: I disagree with the premise that Stack Overflow is not for beginner programmers. Beginners are tolerated just fine. The *problem* is with the lack of research shown, it is questions that are posted without sharing the research done that are badly received. How would a new site solve that?

Comment: FWIW, that first sentence of the help center is pretty much fluff, not actually part of the rules. I haven't seen anyone point to it and say 'you obviously don't love programming, your question is off topic per rule (0)(b)'.

Comment: Your example is an error *anyone* new to Python could make and if you're under time pressures (for whatever reason) your understanding of the error message can be compromised.

Comment: Fyi: This has been suggested and heavily discussed before, and the consensus was that a Stack Overflow for Beginners site would never be a site we would create. I'd try finding some of the previous discussions about this if I weren't on mobile.

Comment: Valid. Please don't just give up on this; it's a real area where improvement *could* be made. No one knows how, though, and we're poking holes in this because we're software people and there are holes to poke. If you find the silver bullet for helping beginners and keeping a site intact at the same time, that'd be awesome.

Comment: The screenshot version was not the revision that was closed, by the way; what is shown is quite different from the version that was closed. I'm not saying it is better, but the context was different.

Comment: The SE network sites are a collection of Q/A's organized around a topic. That topic attracts a crowd. By the way this proposal is defined it is mixing both, the topic and the crowd/visitors. So far that only worked somewhat for the language SO sites. I don't see how it could work if you segregate the crowd/visitors/users on competence.

Comment: Good to know my feedback is interpreted as arguing for the sake of arguing. I thought I brought up some good points here, but alas I'm just tooting the horn of the meta train. _sigh_.

Comment: @Undo 'FWIW, that first sentence of the help center is pretty much fluff, not actually part of the rules.'  OK, please remove it so that fewer skilled and experienced developers are misled into wasting their time on continual beginner duplicates.

Comment: TBH, I'm not totally against some kind of SOS as a trial. Obviously, there would be problems, not the least of which would be 'if it's a fiasco, how do we cleanly walk away from it?'

Comment: The current SO is just about stable.  The number of meta posts about annoyingly-repeated, no-effort beginner questions is in the same order as the number of posts about mob-downvoting jerks with no tolerance for newbies.  There are just about enough skilled and experienced developers still hanging around to answer good questions.  The voting fraud is mostly under control.  The plagiarism is mostly kept on top of.   The thing is, there is a lot of factors, and it's a very unstable sort of stability. If you push it too much it may topple over.  I suspect that an SOS site may be a push too far:(

Comment: Where would the line be drawn between the two SOs? We have good canonical answers in SO already; would e.g. NullPointerException questions on SOS be directed at them? Would the topic be duplicated? What about beginner questions on SO, would they be migrated? What about old beginner questions? Who would decide what _makes_ a beginner question?

Comment: @ModusTollens ...and there's question of what to do about rep.  Would there be an exchange rate?  One 'real' for every 10 'student', or would the sites be completely divorced, ie. student rep essentially worthless once they enter the job market?   Too many issues:(

Comment: This proposal has been made many times over many years. It always sounds like a good idea at first blush. Indeed, it's exactly what many of my friends will come up with when I mention the problems of Stack Overflow in passing. However, that's because they haven't thought through the consequences or implementation. Once you point that out to them, they immediately realize it won't work. We've done that *ad nauseum* here on Meta before. There is just no reason to do it again and again. This is a duplicate many times over. Furthermore, this is not the place to discuss new Area 51 sites.

Comment: One reason to oppose this idea that I don't see mentioned often: When you're talking about skill, remember that most people have different levels of skill in different areas. For example my Perl is relatively strong, but my skill with SciKit Learn (a machine learning framework) is beginner level. I use StackOverflow for both, and my question quality is worse (though hopefully still acceptable) in the latter. You can't reduce most people to a single number.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate: the duped questions explicitly suggest segregating users by reputation. This question proposes a new site.

Comment: @Him wat? there's 3 linked dupes, 2 are for a separate site. All three present the same answer

Comment: [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253646/create-a-new-stack-overflow-instance-for-beginner-users-and-content) proposes a new site, but based on segregation by rep threshold, which seems to be why it was duped to the other "segregate by rep threshold" question, and is the aspect of the question answerers focused on.  [The third](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294172/how-can-i-propose-a-new-stack-exchange-community) is a generic site proposal mechanism, which isn't relevant here at all.

Answer (score 33):

The thing about programming, is that as technology changes and you move onto new projects you're *always* a beginner at *something*.

While it's true that there are concepts that, once you've grasped them, will go with you regardless of what language or framework you're using, there will always be those questions that, to the experts in that language or framework, mark you out as a beginner. This could be something as simple as using the wrong terminology for a concept you're familiar with in some other technology.

There have been many times I've struggled to find the information I needed because I wasn't familiar with the terminology. In several cases I got as far as writing a question but luckily the "related questions" search popped something up that gave me the correct terminology so I was then able to do a better, more focused, search.

So, would I, as a programmer with 30+ years of experience, be allowed to ask a question on that site for a language or framework I was unfamiliar with?

Or, why would a true novice programmer want to ask a question there when all the experts are on SO?

Unless you can attract a whole bunch of experienced people who are willing to answer questions from complete beginners the site is going to become the inexperienced speaking to the ignorant (in the "lacking knowledge" sense). Which, to my mind, is not a recipe for a successful site.

Comment: Well there would need to be experienced people on the new site to answer the questions.

Comment: @YvetteColomb how do you plan on attracting them?

Comment: By posting about it here, to see if it's viable and if it gets enough support it will work, if not it will be deleted.

Comment: I don't mind answering a typical beginner question..once or twice.  Unfortunately, as we all know, NPE, 'i++ + ++i', sprintf.. etc would form an even larger %age of an SOS site than they currently do on SO:(

Comment: @ChrisF I would praticipate on such a site.

Answer (score 23):

There are a few key issues with your proposal:

- Your belief that Stack Overflow isn't meant for beginners.
- You believe that beginner-style questions aren't welcome here.
- You believe that experts will flock to another site for the sole purpose of helping beginners.

In turn...

The idea that SO isn't meant for beginners **directly conflicts** with the policy that we don't cater *specifically* to beginners.  We as answerers are more than happy to answer questions within specific parameters, but overall, we don't explicitly go out of our way to guide and nurture truly rookie developers.

That's ***not*** to say that we're beginner-hostile.

To your example, anyone that felt like they would want to answer that question *could* have.  There's no doubt in my mind that the question would incur downvotes, simply because of the reason we downvote questions:  no research effort, unclear, or not useful.  I would genuinely argue that the OP could've found their answer had they spent a few more minutes in the documentation as opposed to immediately turning to us.

That brings me to the second bullet point:  beginner-style questions are just fine here.  All we ask is that the asker do **a bit more research** into the subject matter and **come to the table as equal partners** in problem solving, and not expecting us to just solve their problem.

We're not getting paid to participate here*.  We're doing this out of our own volunteer time, and our time is precious to us.  If we're here to help, all we're realistically asking is that you be willing to participate, too.

We've had massive homework dumps here before, and we've had simple, "help me understand this facet of my homework" problems here, too.  We welcome the latter and shun the former, not because of any perceived skill level, but because **these aren't the kinds of questions we want to answer.**

This, again, brings me to my next (and final) point:  **experts aren't going to shift.**  They're quite comfortable here answering questions *here* and have built up quite a nice reputation for themselves doing so, and it wouldn't benefit them to shift.

Hell, I'm having a hard enough time getting my own group of friends and fellow programmers to participate here, because the experts on *this* site aren't looking at their questions!

**Can you understand how *frustrating* it is** to have to put up with [*this* garbage for a week](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44599053/1079354)?  Where all you get are people who just glance at the damn documentation and make a half-assed guess at what your problem is?  And worse, they're *only* clearly there just because you've magically attached a bounty to it, and they really don't get your problem?  **That is *damn* frustrating.**  I wouldn't wish that on any rookie, ever.

Now imagine the problem exacerbated for beginners.  It would be ***hell***.  The platform would crash and burn within a week.  There's nothing to sustain it; the experts that the beginners would want to associate with wouldn't give them the time of day, and the ones that would stick around would be leading blind.

---

All of this is to say that **Stack Overflow is *fine* for beginners, students, and rookies alike.**  All we're asking of those groups is that they come to the table prepared to show their work.  If they're not, then they don't need to be here.

<sup>*:  Depends on if your employer looks at your reputation score as something to behold, or if you use Stack Overflow Jobs.</sup>

Comment: **Comments have been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251699/discussion-on-answer-by-makoto-can-we-make-stack-overflow-student-a-success); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements belong in a separate [answer](/help/how-to-answer). Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 14):

Stack Overflow is for beginners too. Stack Overflow helped me lots and lots of times from the very beginning when I've started writing **my own code**.

Everyone is started as a beginner and learned accordingly. When I started coding, I always sent my queries to google and google respond with thousands of results and the first or second result will be a link to stack overflow post.

So that's the best way for beginners to start with stack overflow. Search, search and keep searching.

In the screenshot, that's a question that can be solved with basic knowledge. But the person didn't show any research effort with regards to the term function arguments or parameters in Python. Questions that don't show research effort have a tendency toward not being well received here. That means including links to similar questions that didn't solve the problem.

So, SO is for beginners too but being a beginner is not an excuse for posting questions without showing research effort.

Comment: 'Google respond with thousands of results and the first or second result will be a link to stack overflow post' exactly.  If only others would follow that example:(

Comment: _"A question without any effort is not so suitable here"_ Is an ambiguous statement that may be interpreted in a manner that would be absolutely incorrect. We want research effort, meaning references to similar questions _on Stack Overflow_ that didn't solve the problem.