# What does it mean "to focus on one problem only"?

Tags: support, close-reasons

My last two questions on Stackoverflow had the feedback of "not focusing on single problem".

The last question was about "pros and cons of adding a foreign library to Flutter".

Why is asking about pros and cons not accepted as focused. Do SO moderation use the word focused in a more sophisticated meaning than unusual or do I have a wrong conception about the word focused than dictionaries.

Do I always have to copy and paste some code and ask about an error due to a typo -to be counted as using SO properly?

Comment: Pros and cons aren't inherently too broad, they can be effective Q+As sometimes. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pros+and+cons%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com It depends on the topic in question. Want to post a link to it? Narrowing down what sort of thing(s) you're concerned about specifically can help too.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I deleted it and got my "Peer Pressure" badge. If the feedback was something like "unnecessarily long question" or "redundant wording" I would understand it.

Comment: It means that your Question is too broad. It needs to focus on a specific question. The wording of the feedback is just... unfortunate. And yes, Stack Overflow is currently curated in such a way that unless you put code into your Question, it's likely to get closed as lacking focus, as that close reason is also used in place of "Lacks research", which for a lot of other users mean you didn't show effort.. which means code ..sorry :(

Comment: You can post a screenshot of the question if you don't want to undelete it if you want specific feedback on how it might be improved / made on topic (and/or if the closure of the question was even justified). Code isn't necessary in a question, but (just for example) no code in combination with a very short question body is rarely received well.

Comment: @Scratte I feel like you feel me. Next time I will paste some code from Flappy Bird to give the impression that I am trying hard.

Comment: I don't know if you did this or not, but if you looked into the topic before posting the question, you can put in the question a summary of what you've learned so far, so as to invite others to add to it or clarify points in their answers.

Comment: pros and cons questions tend to suffer from the [gorilla vs shark problem](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Comment: @Xfce4 That made me laugh :) Just remember that if the code you use in your Question is completely unrelated, if will get closed as "Needs details or clarity" :) You should read the help pages about [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).. and maybe all the other help pages too. It may give you a better idea of what to expect.

Comment: @RobertLongson If a question is asking "which is better", that's definitely a red flag for likely POB, but just asking for pros and cons (with the conclusion being left to the reader) should be all right, if the question doesn't have any other issues

Comment: POB means "Primarily Opinion Based".

Comment: Opinions are varied and you may also want to check out [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/12695027), which I'm not a fan of. I like this one though: [Is it always a good idea to demand the OP “post some code”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286760/12695027). And always avoid words like: best, fastest, nicest, cleanest, optimal..

Comment: @Xfce4 Is it possible people took issue with "**a** foreign library" as opposed to you asking about a specific library? Would the pros and cons not depend on which you used?

Comment: @Scratte If someone simply asks a question here the first thing, then that means they didn't do research. Not **_all_** questions have to have code, just a little research and some effort is all I ask.

Comment: @BSMP I see your point. But the question is just about that if you inspect it. As I am trying to find the most adventageous solution, I can not specify a language. It is even possible that I quit using Flutter if all foreign packages result in big issues like frequent crashes for example.

Comment: @BSMP There are points that you need to keep question broad because you can not see what is behind. Instead of making assumptions and drawing strict lines, it is better to leave these to the person who prefers to answer.

Answer (score 10):

> Why is asking about pros and cons not accepted as focused. Do SO
> moderation use the word focused in a more sophisticated meaning than
> unusual or do I have a wrong conception about the word focused than
> dictionaries.

First and foremost: We only have a limited number of close reasons available, and their wording might not precisely apply for each and every question that will be closed for it.

The term *Needs more focus* formerly was *too broad*, and I personally believe it wasn't necessarily the best change to achieve more clarity at the site of the questioners.

Anyways that reason will be used for

- *Too broad* questions (E.g. some topic covered in whole books)
- Polling questions (as you're referring to) which will lead to endless, undecidable discussions. If there are well known and concise points, these questions could be valid. It depends and needs to be decided for every single case.
- Questions which contain a bunch of questions in the body, each deserving a separate question asked

> Do I always have to copy and paste some code and ask about an error
> due to a typo -to be counted as using SO properly?

Code examples aren't strictly necessary if the question isn't about code.
If the question is asking about non-working code (be it due to a typo or not) require a minimal example that can be just copied and tried by anyone else to reproduce the error.

If it's really a problem raised due to a typo or some very basic missing in the programming language (e.g. missing indentation in python, wrong use of well-documented functions, etc.) in the code, it isn't considered to be helpful for future research, because it's a problem very specific to the asker.
These questions will be closed, and most probably deleted. Answers about the wrong thing in the code, are often given as comments, to be at least helpful for the asker.

Comment: How about looking it that way: "There is no wrong questions, but wrong answers"?
If I ask about a "best", some sane community person can first teach me that the best depends on the aim and purpose. If I ask "too broad" another community person can narrow it down to a specific case to be an example about focusing. I am pretty sure it will take much less time for SO moderation to educate people that way.

Comment: @Xfce4 The main goal is to have a precise question and concise answers. Not necessarily a single answer (because sometimes there aren't all aspects covered in one answer), but it should help best for future research of everyone, not only the concerns of the asker. Think about a FAQ, you don't want to read endless discussions there, which won't help to make a decision at all in the end.

Comment: Do you really think a question with title "Flutter is missing some packages. How about this solution? Advantages/disadvantages?" will not help for future research of everyone more than the asker?

Comment: I don't even know about Flutter, I was trying to address the general concerns you brought up here.

Comment: @Xfce4 There are a few small problem with community members teaching new users. There are a lot more new Questions/users than seasoned users able to help. I almost always comment to instruct users when something's off. Maybe 1/20 respond. Of those maybe 1/5 actually improve their post. Of those a small handful will address all the issues I pointed out. Most users will abandon their post as soon as they find a solution. They seem to not care to make their post usable for others. After a while helping new users starts to feel like a hopeless and useless task.

Comment: @Scratte You have really strong points. How about this solution: Make a free environment like "StackOverFlow Flow". Let people rumble there and if a Q&A thread is helpful put that into Stackoverflow as a genuine environment. People who use "SO Flow" well would be promoted to SO.

Comment: @Xfce4 _SO Flow ..._ Well we have chat rooms for that. You can just use them before asking a question at the main site if you're not sure.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The thing is discussions in chat are fluttering while they persist in forums. You don't need to wait in close range of laptop, divide your work and check the browser frequently once the platform is a forum.

Comment: @Xfce4 SO (and othe sites in the SE network) aren't _forums_, and that's what makes them distinct. If you're not satisfied how questions are handled here, feel free to visit Reddit or Quora instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I already asked a programming language question on Quora. And I think more and more people will discover they can do that.

Comment: @Xfce4 We never said you can't. SO just focuses at a differen't model, and usually professionals are more satisfied with what they find here for their daily needs.

Comment: @Xfce4 The idea of a split site is not new. You can start with [Can we make Stack Overflow Student a success?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358240/can-we-make-stack-overflow-student-a-success) and work your way through the duplicate Questions, if you like. There was also a mentoring project [Mentorship Research Project - Results + Wrap-Up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up/357224#357224). Unless you've spent a few months buried in meta, I think you can expect that your idea has been proposed already :)