# How should I deal with a question that mainly contains a link to a service/product?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, spam

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71479707/14277722) as *spam* because it contains mainly a link to a website that offers a paid service. The code example that would make the link redundant and the question obviously *not spam* and well-formed is provided in OP's self-answer. My flag was declined as *a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*. I can understand the decline (but still disagree as unintentional promotion is indistinguishable from spam).

But why was this question closed as *needs to be more focused*?

Comment: I know this isn't your actual question but re: *"I can understand the decline (but still disagree as unintentional promotion is indistinguishable from spam)."* - I don't understand this. Spam is intentional unsolicited promotional content, what's the parenthetical comment trying to say?

Comment: FWIW, *many* people treat the website linked to by the question as a common reference for the language. Unless the author of the question is actually affiliated to the website, it is just a reference like any other.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine - That you could disguise spam as an unintended mention of a product or service in your question, if you want us to distinguish between the two cases. I hope this makes it clearer. Please feel free to edit my question to make it proper english.

Comment: Are you wondering why the question was closed, or why it was closed with that reason? Would you have expected another close reason?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Ah, so you're talking about intelligent spammers who are actually competent at hiding their affiliation when spamming, gotcha, cheers.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - I would like to know how to handle similar questions in the future, but would be uncomfortable to use 'needs more focus'. I think closing is the right decision.

Comment: Mods have some more tools to check if the author is possibly affiliated or not, and if they're not 100% certain, they usually will be more considerate and leave it for now, since red flags carry heavy penalties (100 rep + temporary IP block). As for the closure, ["needs more focus" used to be "too broad"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400968/2821954) and it's still often used with the former intent.

Comment: @AndrewT. - I didn't know about reputation penalties before. That makes it even more understandable to decline my spam flag.

Comment: This wasn't spam. I double-checked. The user isn't promoting anything there. There is no evidence that they're affiliated with the website that they linked, which is a standard reference. What they were doing was posting a "stub" of a question so they could self-answer. I, frankly, thought you were flagging it as spam because you were not aware that SO encourages self-answering, not simply because it contained a link. (Self-answering is fine, but the question still needs to be good and meet our minimum standards. That one didn't, which is why I *also* closed it, after declining the spam flag.)

Comment: "Needs more focus" *is* closing. It is one of the close reasons that are available to choose from in the dialog. There are several of them that would have applied; you could have picked any of them. In this case, I actually think the question *did* lack focus, but it also lacked clarity. Regarding spam: in the future, if it's non-obvious spam, then skip the spam flag. Instead, raise a custom flag for moderator attention where you are given the ability to *explain* your concerns. Even if we decline to take action, it's less likely we'd decline a flag making a reasonable argument.

Comment: Hello, I am the author of the post. I just removed the link: as you already found out I am not affiliated and it was just a reference for me (I find the website one of the best resources, I was not aware that offering paid services makes it to be avoided on SO).
However, I still think that the question is valuable, since I couldn't find a comparison of the speed of different access methods on SO (small doubt, but still useful for me). I accept that it may lack focus/clarity, and I'm willing to improve it if someone can elaborate on this (e.g. linking a similar but better-formed question).

Comment: @Gabriele It is *not* the case that suggesting paid services should be avoided on SO. Pretty much the *only* requirements we have are: (A) it must be relevant to the question that is asked, and (B) if you are affiliated with it, you must include a disclaimer note of your affiliation. This is covered by [the Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). If you're contributing useful, relevant answers, then please don't let this discourage you from continuing to do so. The *main* problem for me was really that the question was too...terse. You've fixed that now; thanks!

Comment: The current form/presentation of the question may not be perfect, but it now meets what I consider to be the minimum requirements for a question, so I've reopened it. I am not a Python programmer, so I cannot provide any real insights on how to improve it further or engage in any technical discussion, but I can say that I definitely think this *general form* of Q&A could be helpful to others and therefore a useful contribution to SO's knowledge base, with the caveat that they need to be fairly narrowly scoped in terms of the options to be compared. This one looks like it is.

Comment: Great to read that, thanks for helping to improve it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretend the link is not there and judge the question based on the immediately accessible content. Most likely it will need *details or clarity* or *debugging details* to be answerable.
However, depending on which parts are "missing" because they are contained in a link, different close reasons may apply as well. For example, if one were to ask about *all possible* ways to do something and only the link constraints the selection then the question may need *more focus*.

The link possibly being spam is a red herring. Unless you have reason to suspect the author is affiliated with the linked resource *and* does not disclose the affiliation, judge the question on its own merits.

Answer (score 1):

There *are* ways to determine if something is "unintentional promotion" or spam. In this case:

- OP has some rep
- The other posts of theirs I checked didn't have any links, much less references to the linked site
- OP's profile lists their workplace and website, neither of which seems to be related to this website
- The question and link are on a subject that's on topic here. (The question is poorly written but that doesn't make it spam.)
- There probably isn't any evidence on the linked site that would suggest that OP is affiliated with them. (I didn't have time to check.)

In light of all these factors, I would expect that a moderator would not delete the post as spam, especially since that subtracts 100 points from the author's reputation, locks the post, and may rate limit or block them. To me, it just looks like the website was something that OP found helpful.